# javascript - Google Chrome cluttering Array generated from .split()

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, google-chrome, split

Given the following string:

```
var str = "one,two,three";
```

If I split the string on the commas, I normally get an array, as expected:

```
var arr = str.split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

Trouble is that in Google Chrome (for Mac), it appends extra properties to the array.

Output from Chrome's debugger:

```
arr: Array
    0: one
    1: two
    2: three
    constructor: function Array()
    index: undefined
    input: undefined
    length: 3
```

So if I iterate over the array with a `for/in` loop, it iterates over the new properties. Specifically the `input` and `index` properties. Using `hasOwnProperty` doesn't seem to help.

A fix would be to do a `for` loop based on the length of the Array. Still I'm wondering if anyone has insight into why Chrome behaves this way. Firefox and Safari don't have this issue.

Comment: @KennyTM: why not `str.split(',');`?

Comment: It's pretty clear patrick is doing that to remove whitespace padding from the items in the resultant array.

Comment: @Peter: indeed, my comment was aimed at KennyTM as I'm not sure why you would use a regex for splitting on a comma only.

Comment: So it sounds like `for/in` over an array is bad. Point taken. Still curious about why Chrome would try to iterate `input` and `index`. Or why they're there at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't iterate over arrays using `for...in` loops!!  This is one of the many pitfalls of Javascript ([plug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749952/what-are-the-top-javascript-pitfalls/2901139#2901139)) - `for...in` loops are for iterating over object properties only.

Use normal for loops instead.

```
for (var i=0, max = arr.length; i < max; i++) { ... }
```

---

Firefox and Safari's ECMAScript/Javascript engines make those particular properties non-enumerable (`{DontEnum}` attribute), so they would not be iterated over in a `for...in` loop.  Still, `for...in` loops were not intended to iterate over array indexes.

Comment: you forgot to use the max variable you defined ;)

Comment: @Gaby: yes I just realized that myself lol.  It's been a long day :-)

Comment: Your edit seems to be the key. Chrome doesn't make those properties non-enumerable for some reason. I'll stick to a length based loop.

Answer (score 3):

`For..in` is for iterating over enumerable properties of objects.  For an array, to iterate over its indicies, just use a standard for loop

```
for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length, i < l; i++ )
{
  // do whatever with arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly relevant to this particular problem, but note that splitting strings with regular expressions has all sorts of cross-browser issues. See http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split for more info, and for solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Pointy.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over an array with a for/in loop is not recommended, in general. First of all the order of iteration is not guaranteed, and in addition, you risk issues like the one you are having. You are better off using a traditional for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that using a regexp here results in an array-like object, much like the result of the execution of [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

I could not reproduce the bug on Chrome/Win7, but I suggest to use the `Array.prototype.slice.call(arr)` magic. It is known for perfectly turning array-likes into real arrays.