# Javascript, script not working in IE

Tags: javascript

The routine below works perfectly in Mozilla, but not in IE (I'm using 9 but have changed the compatibility mode and it's broken in 7 and 8 too).

I know that it's something to do with the e.type as 'undefined' in IE, and fine in Moz, but don't know what the correct syntax should be to satisfy both.

```
function changeChartColumns(){
        var myArray = [];
        var k = 1;
        var b = 0;
        myArray[0]=0;
        for (b in document.frm_obj.elements) {
            var e = document.frm_obj.elements[b];
            if ( e.type=="checkbox" ) {
                if(e.checked == true){
                    var at_least_one_checked = true;
                    myArray[k] = parseInt(e.value,10);
                    k = k+1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(at_least_one_checked == true){
            return myArray;
        }else{
            alert("I cannot display zero information. Please select some stuff using the checkboxes.");
            stop_script_running; // horrible hack
        }
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<form name="frm_obj" id="frm_obj" method="post">
      <table>   
        <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="list" value="2" checked onClick="changeChartColumns();"></td>
         <td>Option 1</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="list" value="3" checked onClick="changeChartColumns();"></td>
         <td>Option 2</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="list" value="4" checked onClick="changeChartColumns();"></td>

       </table>
     </form>
```

Thanks in advance. H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper `for` loop:

```
    for (var i=0; i < document.frm_obj.elements.length; i++) {
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y7xFz/1**

`for...in` is designed to iterate over all enumerable properties of an object.  `document.frm_obj.elements` returns a HTMLCollection, whose enumerable properties differ between browsers.  In general, you shouldn't use `for...in` on arrays and HTMLCollections - reserve use for object maps with named properties only.

Comment: Just to further this, the reason why it doesn't work is that the `for..in` loop on a form accesses the each element by name and thus when you request the `type` of a checkbox and there is a "set" of checkboxes with the same name, it returns `undefined`.  This occurs with both radio or checkbox elements when there is more than one.  When there is only 1 radio or checkbox element it will work fine.

Comment: @scunliffe: that's not the problem here - he's accessing the `elements` collection of a named `form` object, which returns a HTMLCollection.  In IE, none of the elements within a HTMLCollection are enumerable, but the properties `item`, `list`, `length` and `namedItem` are.  So with a `for...in`, you're actually iterating over those properties rather than the elements within the collection.

Comment: ah yes, in this case, in IE, that's what is iterated over - silly IE.  The original JavaScript docs (v1.0) was a collection of form elements.  Quote from the Netscape JavaScript docs: *"Each Form object (which itself is an element of the document.forms array) has an elements array that reflects the text boxes, buttons, and other elements in an HTML form..."* - oh well, good to know that IE throws in extra content and thus a for..in loop is seriously not the way to iterate over the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getAttribute()` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>( b.type == "checkbox" )</strike>

[Also,] at_least_one_checked is defined in the local if block.

Comment: JavaScript only has function scope (except for a few exceptions).  `if` blocks and `for` loops do not have their own scope, so if a variable is defined in one of those blocks it is available to the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code replace the below line

```
for (b in document.frm_obj.elements) {
```

with this one

```
for (b in document.body.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
```

This way it will also work in IE.

Comment: You shouldn't use `for...in` loops on arrays and HTMLCollections.  See my answer for an explanation.  Also, what if there is more than one form in the document?